# Wholesale Price is not display in front end

Tags: admin, price, frontend

I am working in magento admin panel.My problem is when i create a product then its Wholesale Price is not display in front end. How the wholesale price display in front end. Admin > Add Product > Prices .... Attached screenshot[image]

Comment: Can you post exactly what you are doing, where you are doing it? Is the wholesale price set to a customer group, are you logged in as that customer group, etc, etc.

Comment: I am setting Wholesale Price for product from admin panel. Check question updated with screenshot. This price is not display in front end.

Comment: for which version 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: Version is 1.x.